# Simple PostGIS XYZ set up?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am new to PostGIS. I am looking to have a simple bounded (-200 < x, y, z < 200) data set of 1,000,000 points on a plain XYZ graph. The only query I need is a fast K nearest neighbors and all neighbors such that the distance is less than < N. It seems that PostGIS has a LOT of extra features that I do not need.

- What do SRID do I need? One that does not concern with feet or meters.
- Am I right that I need to use the function
  ST_3DDistance to query for the K nearest neighbors with LIMIT K? or with a maximum distance of N.
- To add a column, I need to use `SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('my_schema','my_spatial_table','geom_c',4326,'POINT',3, false);`. Is that correct?

  - What is the difference between a 3D point and a PointZ?
  - Will AddGeometryColumn  ensure that my distance query is fast?
- Is PostGIS the right choice for my use case? The rest of my DB is already integrated with PostgreSQL

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do SRID do I need? One that does not concern with feet or meters.

You don't "need" a srid. If your data is a in a coordinate system, find the right srid, otherwise, use 0.

> Am I right that I need to use the function ST_3DDistance to query for the K nearest neighbors with LIMIT K? or with a maximum distance of N.

Yes, you're right.

> To add a column, I need to use SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('my_schema','my_spatial_table','geom_c',4326,'POINT',3, false);. Is that correct?

Yes, but I'd use 0 for srid, instead of 4326 (that is for degrees).

> What is the difference between a 3D point and a PointZ?

PointZ is a 3d Point.

> Will AddGeometryColumn ensure that my distance query is fast?

AddGeometryColumn will just add some constraints to the table, ensuring that the geometries you insert are coherent with the column definition.

I don't think you need it, but you could try adding an index to your geometry column using CREATE INDEX index_name ON schema.table USING gist (geom_col);

> Is PostGIS the right choice for my use case? The rest of my DB is already integrated with PostgreSQL

I think it is the easiest way, not necessarly the "right" one.

You could also implement a distance function without postgis, storing the three coordinates in three numeric fields.

Comment: _"You could also implement a distance function without postgis, storing the three coordinates in three numeric fields."_ I was thinking about this! From my understanding, if i built a naive implementation, this would be slow. It would need to scan all entries in the DB per query and do a distance calculation. I believe PostGIS solves this problem, am I correct in thinking that?

Comment: How do I set up the column such that the distance query does not have to do a full table scan? I thought `AddGeometryColumn` solved that with an index. Would `CREATE INDEX index_name ON schema.table USING gist (geom_col);` take care of adding an index that'd help with 3D distance queries?

Comment: If you implement the function by yourself, you should be able to optimize your query for your needs. For example, you could restrict the "candidates" using a min x, max x, min y, max y (bouding box), if it fits...

Comment: I don't think the index will help, I think it is worth trying with and without and analyze the query plan

Comment: However, I'd go with the easiest solution first.. If it's too slow, we can find a way to optimize it, maybe building a custom index.